# Pip/Conda install Quantipy throws failed wheels error

Tags: python-3.x, pip, package, installation, conda

Trying to install the python library Quantipy. When I try to install with Pip from command line I get a very lengthy error. I am using `Python 3` with `Anaconda` distribution.

pip install quantipy

Should install correctly, but this is the output:

> ---
>
> Failed building wheel for quantipy
>     Running setup.py clean for quantipy
>   Failed to build quantipy
>   Installing collected packages: quantipy
>     Running setup.py install for quantipy ... error
>       Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6jrxianp\quantipy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1dg6hdcy\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:470: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.0.0dev3' to '0.0.0.dev3'
>         normalized_version,
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy
>       copying quantipy\mplrcsettings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy
>       copying quantipy__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\correlations
>       copying quantipy\correlations\correlations.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\correlations
>       copying quantipy\correlations\dynspecfunc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\correlations
>       copying quantipy\correlations__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\correlations
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\lattice
>       copying quantipy\lattice\lattice.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\lattice
>       copying quantipy\lattice__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\lattice
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\models
>       copying quantipy\models\genericmodel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\models
>       copying quantipy\models\quadratic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\models
>       copying quantipy\models\spinwave.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\models
>       copying quantipy\models\test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\models
>       copying quantipy\models\tightbinding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\models
>       copying quantipy\models__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\models
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\operators
>       copying quantipy\operators\heisenberg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\operators
>       copying quantipy\operators__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\operators
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\quicked
>       copying quantipy\quicked\quicked.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\quicked
>       copying quantipy\quicked__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\quicked
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\spectra
>       copying quantipy\spectra\spectra.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\spectra
>       copying quantipy\spectra__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\spectra
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\spglib
>       copying quantipy\spglib\spglib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\spglib
>       copying quantipy\spglib\spglib2d.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\spglib
>       copying quantipy\spglib__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\spglib
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\symmetries
>       copying quantipy\symmetries\symmetries.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\symmetries
>       copying quantipy\symmetries__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\symmetries
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\towerofstates
>       copying quantipy\towerofstates\towerofstates.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\towerofstates
>       copying quantipy\towerofstates__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\towerofstates
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\utils
>       copying quantipy\utils\decorator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\utils
>       copying quantipy\utils\findfiles.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\utils
>       copying quantipy\utils\geometryutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\utils
>       copying quantipy\utils\pathdistance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\utils
>       copying quantipy\utils\pfaffian.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\utils
>       copying quantipy\utils\plotutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\utils
>       copying quantipy\utils\rowoperations.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\utils
>       copying quantipy\utils\sun_combinatorics.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\utils
>       copying quantipy\utils__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\quantipy\utils
>       running build_ext
>       No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>       building '_quicked' extension
>       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quantipy](https://quantipy-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is at an early stage of development,
not yet offering good binary install support. (0.0.0.dev3)

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

At this stage in the package's maturity, you will need to obtain Visual C++ 14 prior to doing a successful `pip install`.

EDIT

It is possible you sought a similarly named package, https://github.com/quantipy/quantipy3.
It is unrelated to lattices for quantum many-body computations.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what I need to download from that link? I don't see anything titled exactly "Visual C++ 14" . Thanks

Comment: It would be worth logging a bug against the quantiply package. Microsoft may have changed their site since last package update. I just see options like "Visual Studio for Mac", which probably isn't relevant to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install a python 2 module on python 3. There is no quantipy version for python 3 as of yet.